# Starting Dev with PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows-7

I have written web apps with JSP in the past. Now, I'm getting started with PHP. I have a question and a friend of mine who is a .NET developer pointed me to this site.

I downloaded and installed PHP from [here](http://php.iis.net/). Now, I'm trying to get the Windows Azure for PHP SDKs setup. The reason for this is that my app needs to be hosted in Azure. After I downloaded the SDK, I looked in the install.txt file. The file states that I need to add the library directory to my PHP include_path. My problem is, I do not see an environment variable named "include_path" in my settings. Should one have been created? Is the PHP include_path even an environment variable?  Can someone help me out please?

Thank you!

Comment: I've never used PHP with IIS, but I can tell you that `include_path` is not an ENV variable but a config setting. check out `set_include_path()`, `get_include_path()` and the `PATH_SEPARATOR` constant. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include_path` is a configuration setting usually set in the [`php.ini`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) file.

Run a PHP script containing

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

to find out which php.ini is actually being used - it can be confusing sometimes.

The INI file will contain the setting, which you can then change.

You will probably need to restart the web server after changes.

I don't know how PHP and Azure work together. If the INI method doesn't apply here, [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) is the PHP manual section on ways to change PHP config settings other than php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a dedicated development system like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).  Although it should be noted that XAMPP should **NEVER** be used on a production system.  It is very insecure and they are very very very slow at patching known vulnerabilities in their stack.

Answer (score 0):

Question: If you're planning on building an Azure based system, why are you choosing to build it in PHP rather than C# on ASP.NET?

.NET is Microsoft's primary platform for web infrastructure development: Azure support will come quicker and will be FAR more thorough for .NET vs. any other platform.

Remember: "Just because you can doesn't mean you should" ;)

I strongly encourage you to build your Azure site in .NET, not PHP.